# trying to use webpack with existing angular1 applicaiton

Tags: webpack, build, config, angular1.6

I have a existing angular1 app which i am trying to implement web pack

Source code is modified

and the webpack is as shown below

All the dependencies are  included in package.json

following this post

```
http://matthamil.me/blog/Angular-1-and-Webpack/

import webpack from 'webpack';

module.exports = {
    // This creates a source map to make your
    // console errors a lot more developer friendly
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    // Webpack will start doing its thing here
    entry: {
        app: './app/app.js',
        vendor: ['angular']
    },
    // Where Webpack spits the output
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename:  "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        // These are Webpack plugins (commonly referred
        // to as "loaders" in the Webpack community).
        // Babel will compile our ES6 to ES5
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**when i run webpack the following error is displaying**

```
/home/dl/projects/zd /webpackangular1app/webpack.config.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import webpack from 'webpack';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:226:18)
```

please say how to use import **webpack**  in webpack.config.js tried many like require inspite of import but no luck please point to reference or suggest a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Node doesn't support the ES import syntax yet, which you are trying to use in your webpack configuration file.

Webpack doesn't pass your configuration files through the loaders etc. that you define, so your config isn't going through Babel.

Change this:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
```

To this:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
```